# Notation question: dual space basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, vectors, dual-spaces

I have an exercise that I am trying to decipher, but as I have never seen this notation before I do not know how to read it. The problem states:

> *The vectors $x_1=(1,1,1),x_2=(1,1,-1)$ and $x_3=(1,-1,-1)$ form a basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$. If ${y_1,y_2,y_3}$ is the dual basis, and if
>   $x=(0,1,0)$, find $[x,y_1],[x,y_2],[x,y_3]$.*

Can someone help me understand what this last part $[x,y_i]$ means?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It could be the [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Complex_coordinate_space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exercise is from *Halmos: Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces*.

If $V$ is a vector space, $y \in V'$ (the dual space of $V)$ and $x \in V$, the notation $[x, y]$ stands for the scalar $y(x)$, which one obtains when one inserts $x$ into $y$. It is explained in the text why this notation is used.

Comment: Right, that notation, $y(x)$, is what I am used to. That solves it.